# Where does the ren or rename command live in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I have searched my file system for this command, but I can not find it.  It must be aliased somehow, but none of the clever unix utils that I have installed in on Windows machine can help me find it.

Any clue?

Comment: thanks to both grawity and Psycogeek for good answers.  It is also possible to use "cmd /c ren"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is built into the `cmd.exe` shell.

Comment: Type in 'help' at the command to see a list of commands.

Answer (score 6):

Some commands in the command prompt are built into the "shell".  There is a [list here](http://commandwindows.com/command1.htm) of the internals, and a [long reference list here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true).   But they do not seem to be designated there as to being internal or not.

Many internal items can be replaced with better 3rd party external versions, so if you need a executable `rename`, you might be able to find one.

Comment: "the normal way a person would do that"...? Why? Why would using built-in commands be 'not normal'?

Comment: @grawity, I edited that line out, didn't make sense to me either.